Transformation of eigenvalue equation
Let $f(x) = e^{i \omega x^0} u(x^1, x^2, x^3)$ be a scalar function on some spacetime manifold in coordinates $(x^{\mu})$. It satisfies the eigenvalue equation
$$\partial_0 f = i \omega f$$
Since $\partial_{\mu} f$ transforms covariantly
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tilde{x}^{\nu}} \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$$
The left-hand side transforms as
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^0} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tilde{x}^{\nu}} \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^{\nu}}{\partial x^0}$$
The right-hand side, however, is just a scalar function since $f$ is scalar and $\omega$ is an eigenwert. This means the LHS and the RHS transform differently! I assume I am misunderstanding something here, otherwise this would be a major inconsistency. Where is my error?

The eigenvalue equation is obtained by applying an operator to f. In order to se how the equation changes, you have to transform the operator and then apply it to f. It will give you the appropriate eigenvalue equation for the transformed operator, and the transformed f. (you still have to transform $x_0$ in the exponential.)

I dont think I understand. Could you elaborate? My problem is that the operator on the right hand side transforms (in my case) covariantly. But the right hand side is a scalar. But if those two sides are equal, then they should both be either scalar or transform covariantly, shouldnt they? How can they be equal if they differ in their transformstional behaviour?

You can’t transform the eigenvalue equation once you have applied the differential operator. If you want to transform first, apply the change of coordinates to both the operator and f, and then apply the operator. If you do that you will see that there is no contradiction. (You can already see that the $x_0$ in the exponential will transform and after you take the transformed derivative, both sides of the equation will have the same transformation.

Is there any reason to expect the eigenvalue equation to be invariant?

The transformed frequencies are given by $\omega \frac{\tilde{\partial x_\mu}}{\partial x_0}$. Which can be seen by transforming $f=e^{i w x_0} u(x^\mu)$ just like you transform the diff operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$.

Hm, I think I understand my misconception. The eigenvalue equation does not transform covariantly as @Javier hinted at. However, when approaching the problem your way, I arrive at a different result. My approach is
$$\tilde{\partial}0 f = (\partial{\mu} f) (\tilde{\partial}_0 x^{\mu}) = \big( i \omega \tilde{\partial}_0 x^0 + \tilde{\partial}_0 \ln u ) \cdot f$$
If I am not wearing out your patience too much, could you elaborate how you arrived at your expression for the transformed frequencies?
